# how to get the needed package name?

Tags: android, android-manifest

i want to use `<queries>` element in manifest file to broaden the package visibility for my app. I add `<package>` to `<queries>` and then i need to specify the name of the package i want to access from my app:

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="some.package.name"/>
</queries>
```

For example, i want to write in the package name of `gmail` app. **How do i know it?**

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for offline solution then follow these steps.

1-> Download [Current Activity](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=current%20activity&c=apps)

2-> Open then Grant permission if any.

3-> There will be a top floating text 1st text will represent the package name for current opened/displayed app.
[image: Sample illustration]

Comment: can you tell little more about 2 point. How to perform it ?

Comment: basically you need to provide "Display overlay" permission that's allow app to display over other apps. So you can see app related info on top of every app.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest approach is to search that app in Play Store and get it's ID. Basically ID is the package name of that app.
For example:

> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gm

Here `com.google.android.gm` is the package name for Gmail